# How do I make Xcode refresh its local copies of my project's image files?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm having some weird issues with Xcode, and this is pretty much impossible to find answers by simply googling around.

I have a few icon image files (just PNGs) in my Xcode project, and when I modify some of them in Photoshop, they don't get updated when I do another build in Xcode. In order to fix this I have to re-add the file again to the project, and then remove the old version of the file that is already in there in Xcode.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm updating/replacing the image file that is stored in my project's directory directly from Photoshop, so I assumed that it would just get reloaded and the new version would show up.

UPDATE: Looks like what happened was that when I first imported the image files into my project, they got added to my "Classes/" sub-directory. So when I was updating them, it was just adding them to the root of my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty weird.  I'd suggest two things:

1. Check that you're not saving your
   photoshop files into the wrong
   directory.  I know this seems
   straightforward but its worth a
   check.  Make sure you're not saving
   them into the build/ directory or
   anything like that.
2. Before running again in the simulator, try **cleaning** all build targets first to ensure that your project actually builds again before launching the simulator.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that. I can see that the new files have the new width that I used in Photoshop, but the version that shows up in the Simulator is still the old ones.

Also tried cleaning all targets and even restarting Xcode. No go.

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same problem. 
The following fixed it for me:
In Xcode, go to Project --> Clean

This will purge the old images from xcode cache and will show your new image

Comment: Works like a charm, and the quick key is shift + cmd + k